# Convert (x,x) into dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, sql

how do i convert (x,y) into a dataframe?
using python, pandas or any library
code i used to generate these:

```
while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        sql = "SELECT ID, num FROM dbo.stats WHERE id > %s" % (prev_id)
        mycursor.execute(sql) 
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()    
        for x in myresult:
            print(x)
            prev_id = x[0]
```

```
(4271, 7)
(4272, 9)
(4273, 12)
(4274, 6)
(4275, 13)
(4276, 10)
(4277, 1)
(4278, 6)
(4279, 12)
(4280, 0)
(4281, 9)
(4288, 10)
(4289, 8)
```

Comment: (x,y) stored how? As a list of tuples? You may want to show some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the following code,

```
import pandas as pd

d = { 'x': [], 'y': [] } # --> create dict to hold x & y values
for x in myresult:
    print(x)
    prev_id = x[0]

    d['x'].append(x[0])
    d['y'].append(x[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Hi, for this case, only the latest values are thrown into the dataframe right? I just ran the test and only the latest values are in the dataframe. how can i get all the values?

Comment: Yep, it will hold latest values, to hold all the values just create the same dict out of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

what you get from `fetchall` is an iterator.

so by doing

```
mydata = tuple(myresult)
```

you will have your data in python, which should be an answer the way you asked the question.

here's a compact way to get it into a df

```
pd.DataFrame(list(myresult), columns=['x', 'y'])
```